# How to bind value of ImageButton's BorderColor attribute from a String column of a DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have used a DataTable with a String column "border_color". There's a GridView whose dataSource is this DataTable and in a asp:TemplateField there's an ImageButton whose BorderColor attribute I want to bind from the dataTable's column "border_color".
I am trying:-

```
    BorderColor = '<%# Eval("border_color") %>'
```

But I get exception: Invalid cast.

Answer (score 0):

Use the codebehind, the `GridView's` `RowDataBound` event. I assume you store the html color:

```
protected void GrdidView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        string htmlColor = row.Field<string>("border_color");
        Color borderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(htmlColor);
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) e.Row.FindControl("ImageButtonID");
        btn.BorderColor = borderColor;
    }
}
```